# body width 100% after adding dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am giving body height 100% by using this code:-

```
  <div class="container" id="container" style="background-color:#FAFAFA;">
  <div class=" span5 fill">

  </div>
</div>
```

And css is:-

```
  .fill{
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  }


  .container{
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  }
```

But when i am adding dynamic content in 'fill' div, then content not in 100% body tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window

Comment: Thanks for reply, But as in this example now i am using vh for body and fill div, But still not working.

Comment: No problem - I just added a jquery version for you that should help get you close.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you tagged jQuery so here is a simple function that you can use to set the height dynamically. It also changes based on the browser resizing.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xfnyzcos/

jQuery Code:

```
function setHeight(){
    var winHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $(".container").css("height", winHeight + "px");
    $(".fill").css("height", winHeight + "px");
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
});

setHeight();
```

Comment: After adding dynamic content i am calling setHeight() function, but still not working.